# I'm getting an error when using Provider in my react app

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm trying to create a redux store. When i run my program i get this error :

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useMemo')
```

This is my store :

```
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware  } from 'redux'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension'

const reducer = combineReducers({})

const intialState = {}

const middleware = [thunk]

const store = createStore(reducer, intialState, 
    composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middleware)))

export default store
```

and thins is my index.js :

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import store from './store'

import App from './App';


ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

Comment: You should add at least a reducer to your combinereducers(). Please use the package `@reduxjs/toolkit` which is the redux suggested package today, this way it's faster to configure the Store, and thunk middleware is included by default.

Comment: you are trying to combine reducers , thats ok but you have not provide any which doesn't make sense ! So ditch combine reducers and use just one root reducer